# Shift/Reduce conflict with tuples and grouped expressions

Tags: python, parsing

I am trying to parse a programming language, and in it there are tuples (using parenthesis), but also grouped expressions (also using parenthesis). The problem is that the parser doesn't know if it should parse the expression as a tuple, or a grouped expression. Here is the grammar:

```py
@_("'(' expression ')'")
def expression(self, p):
    return p.expression

@_("'(' items ')'")
def tuple(self, p):
    return ("TUPLE", {"ITEMS": p.positional_args, "LINE": p.lineno})
```

I am using [SLY](https://github.com/dabeaz/sly) for parsing, and I can't find a way to change the precedence. I have tried to make the `'('` and `')'` nonassociative, but that does not resolve the conflict. I also tried making the precedence of the expression grouping higher and `nonassoc`, like this:

```py
precedence = (
        ("nonassoc", EXPRESSION_GROUPING),
        # ALSO this:
        ("left", EXPRESSION_GROUPING),
    )

@_("'(' expression ')' %prec EXPRESSION_GROUPING")
def expression(self, p):
    return p.expression
```

That did not resolve the shift reduce conflict either. NOTE: I want expression to be parsed as an expression grouping, not a tuple, if this case happens. For example:

```
(expression_here)
```

Should be parsed as an expression grouping (which is an `expression`) and not a tuple, as I think that is more natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem of precedence; it's a question of the precise grammar for `items`, which you don't show. Presumably, your grammar permits `items` to consist of just one `item`. Since you want that syntax to be an `expression`, it should not be viable as a `tuple`, leading to:

```
items: item ',' item
     | items ',' item
```

In addition you might want to allow a trailling comma, as in Python, to indicate a single-item tuple, and maybe even an empty tuple:

```
 tuple: '(' items ')'
      | '(' items ',' ')'
      | '(' expression ',' ')'
      | '(' ')'
```